# Как соединить два блока div?

Tags: html, css, html5

как склеить два блока?
только начал верстать, новичок. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <div class="info-block">
        <div class="me_img">
            <img src="img/me.jpg" width="300" height="500" alt="123">
        </div>
        <div class="social_links">
            <button class="btn"><i class="vkl"></i></button>
            <button class="btn"><i class="tgl"></i></button>
            <button class="btn"><i class="wpl"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>




.info-block {
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    flex: 10%;
    background-color: #cabcbc;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.social_links {
    width: auto;
    background-color:white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте изучить модель блока (в нашем случае, либо div, либо элемент сверху, к которому соединяемся), чтобы понять, почему он не хочет соединяться. Находится в "Вычисленные" справа в веб-инспекторе

Comment: Проблема в inline-потоке. Удалите лишние пробелы между тегами.

Comment: @DiD, не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

в `.info-block` сделайте `font-size: 0px;`
пропуск возникает из-за перевода строки и кучи пробелов в кода:

```
    </div>
    <div class="social_links">
```

```css
.info-block {
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    flex: 10%;
    background-color: #cabcbc;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    
    font-size: 0px;
}

.social_links {
    width: auto;
    background-color:white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="info-block">
        <div class="me_img">
            <img src="https://news-ru.gismeteo.st/2018/10/fdbd1811.jpg" width="300" height="500" alt="123">
        </div>
        <div class="social_links">
            <button class="btn"><i class="vkl"></i></button>
            <button class="btn"><i class="tgl"></i></button>
            <button class="btn"><i class="wpl"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: если сделать font-size: 0px; то весь текст пропадает, тогда info-block и social_links в отдельный div закинуть?

Comment: ну так для дочерних блоков выставить размер шрифта просто

Comment: Перевод строки между блочными элементами ничего не делает по умолчанию.

Comment: Ответы, конечно, хороши, но ты не поймёшь в чем проблема. Ф12 и смотри где этот пробел и что на это влияет

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать в стилях это:

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Гадание не задалось.

Answer (score 0):

```
.me_img img {
  display: block;
}
```